# ByteBuddy how to create a class file?

Tags: java, byte-buddy, annotation-processing

I'm trying to create a class with annotation processor using ByteBuddy at build time.

I want to create a class and generate source file then generated source file could be invoked and used at runtime.

I want to know what I should do or if I am doing something wrong.

hope your help sincerely.

This is a class That I want to create.

```java
    public class EntitySource {
      static Stream entitySource() {
        return Stream.of(new Member(1L));
      }
    }
```

And here is my implementation.

```java
    File sourceDirectory = new File("Something path of directory");
    sourceDirectory.mkdirs();
    File sourceFile = new File("Something path of directory" + "/EntitySource.java");
    sourceFile.createNewFile();

    new ByteBuddy()
      .subclass(Object.class)  
      .name(generatedClassName)
      .defineMethod("entitySource", Stream.class, Ownership.STATIC, Visibility.PACKAGE_PRIVATE)
      // .defaultValue(FixedValue.value(Stream.of(modelClass.getConstructor(Long.class).newInstance(1L))), Stream.class)
      .intercept(FixedValue.value(Stream.of(modelClass.getConstructor(Long.class).newInstance(1L))))
      .make()
      .load(getClass().getClassLoader(), ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.INJECTION)
      .inject(sourceFile);
```

Contrary to my expectations, generated source is below.. (in intellij IDEA)

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1wDZ.png)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Byte Buddy generates class, not source files.

For source file generation, have a look at [Java Poet](https://github.com/square/javapoet).

Comment: That being said, unless OP really needs a source file for some reason, having a class file should be enough. It sounds like they are mainly interested in using the class at runtime.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Then, there is no way to check class generated visually? 

Comment: you can use a decompiler on the class file. The class file is available from the returned object after "make".